# How to have a link within a popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking for some help in regards to having a link showing within a pop up window. The following is the HTML that I have:

HTML

```
<div id="popup"> 
<a href="#"><div id="popup-headline">News 1</div><div id="local">News Author</div>
<div id="date">| May 24, 2016</div><span><strong>News Text</strong><br /><br />News Text</span></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#popup { color: #000; background-color: #fff; }

#popup a, #popup a:visited {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight:normal;
    color: #0088cc;
}

#popup a span {
    display: none;
}

#popup a:hover { 
    background-color: #fff; 
}

/* the IE correction rule */
#popup a:hover  {
    color: #005580; 
    background-color: #fff;
    text-indent: 0; /* added the default value */
}

#popup a:hover span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border:4px solid #ddd;
    top: 4px;
    left: 60px;
    width: 226px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 8px;
    color: #005580;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#date {
    color: #999;
}

#popup-headline {
    margin-top: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
}

#popup-headline-2 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height: 15px;
}

#local {
    line-height: 15px;
    float: left;
}
```

The problem I have is that I would like to add an anchor link within the news text section i.e. `<a href="link">Click Here</a>` but this breaks the code and the link doesn't appear within the pop up window.

If somebody could please advise if this is possible for me to do as I would really like to know how i can show links.

Thanks in advance.

The website where I found this feature is the following:

http://www.unisonleics.org.uk

At the bottom of homepage on Local News Section if you hover over Branch AGM then a pop up appears, it is in the pop up window where I would like to add a link.

Comment: It's not clear how you're trying to add the `<a>` to your HTML. If it's simply a matter of you trying to nest it inside of the `<a>` that's already there, the answer is simple: you cannot nest hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a link in the popup, and you can't have a link within a link.

Remove the link that is already there, and add your link.

```css
#popup { color: #000; background-color: #fff; }

#popup .content, #popup .content:visited {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight:normal;
    color: #0088cc;
}

#popup .content span {
    display: none;
}

#popup .content:hover { 
    background-color: #fff; 
}

/* the IE correction rule */
#popup .content:hover  {
    color: #005580; 
    background-color: #fff;
    text-indent: 0; /* added the default value */
}

#popup .content:hover span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border:4px solid #ddd;
    top: 4px;
    left: 60px;
    width: 226px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 8px;
    color: #005580;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#date {
    color: #999;
}

#popup-headline {
    margin-top: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
}

#popup-headline-2 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height: 15px;
}

#local {
    line-height: 15px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup"><span class="content">
  <div id="popup-headline">News 1</div><div id="local">News Author</div>
  <div id="date">| May 24, 2016</div><span><strong>News Text <a href="link">Click Here</a></strong><br /><br />News Text</span>
</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses. The problem is that if i remove the first link then then the text next no longer appears in a popup window.

Comment: @user3191160 ah gotcha, just looked at the link in your post. Updated my answer.